# Alias name for model in Laravel 4

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I am working on Laravel 4.1. I have 4 models for four different tables, but in this query I'm trying to get the count for activity, application and query as I'm using alias for the table name, but I can't to give the alias for the model.

Can anyone explain how to give the alias name for the model?

```
return $this->model->select('
      sud.*,
      (select count(saf.userid) 
       from soca_activity_form saf 
       where sud.id = saf.userid  ) activitycount,
      (select count(sa.userid) 
       from soca_applicationform sa 
       where sud.id = sa.userid  ) applicationcount,
      (select count(sqf.userid) 
       from soca_query_form sqf 
       where sud.id = sqf.userid  ) querycount')
->where('admin','!=',1)
->orderBy('id', 'desc')
->paginate(50);
```

SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '.`id = saf`.`userid ) activitycount ,(select count(sa`.`userid) from soca_appli' at line 1 (SQL: select`sud`.`*,(select count(saf`.`userid) from soca_activity_form saf where sud`.`id = saf`.`userid ) activitycount ,(select count(sa`.`userid) from soca_applicationform sa where sud`.`id = sa`.`userid ) applicationcount,(select count(sqf`.`userid) from soca_query_form sqf where sud`.`id = sqf`.`userid ) querycount`from`soca_user_details`where`admin`!= 1 order by`id` desc limit 50 offset 0)

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: I know where is my mistake ie ''from soca_user_details" as I have not given the alias name for this table because the table name is coming from model